# Is it possible that a tag exists in the dom but not on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, dom, xpath

I came across a situation where I found an "anchor" tag in the DOM using xpath but the corresponding element was nowhere to be found on the page and while testing the particular tag, the click() operation worked. Is that even possible?

Comment: I don't think it is. But I think there are specifics missing - when you say "nowhere to be found" on the page, what do you mean? The displayed page, or the source code, or what?

Comment: the displayed page

Comment: In that case, the link could be hidden (not shown), covered up (something is placed in front of it), simply shown but invisible (has no content, so has dimensions of zero) or others. It's entirely possible to have something in the DOM that you cannot see, in fact that's very common.

Comment: this tag has a reference to another page and works when clicked using selenium.

Comment: Irrelevant. As I said, you CAN have a DOM element and not be able to see it. I've even listed three possibilities how that can be achieved. The final one should also work with Selenium. Since there isn't a single way to do this, if you want to know the _exact_ reason you can't currently see an element, then open the developer console and examine it. We can't just say directly what the reason is, without knowing any of the context. The only thing that can be said for sure is a direct answer to the question in the title - yes, the situation is possible.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Check out for the CSS property, specifically

> display : none

Comment: no such property. this tag is however displayed on a different page on the same website.

Comment: what are the css properties applied to this tag. Can you check computer css properties in chrome console.

Comment: background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible options.
Like in the previous answer, it could have `display : none`. If this is not the case for your specific element, it would likely inherit this from a parent node. It's CSS class could contain this, multiple CSS classes may be involved, just to name a few that came to mind.

And now about the `click()` method actually working...this is because Selenium WebDriver doesn't use the regular mouse cursor (the one you're seeing on screen) to do the actual clicking or hovering on element, but everything is done internally.